# Automating VM Creation with Terraform and Cloning a Private GitHub Repository via SSH

Tags: github, ssh, terraform, cloud-init, hetzner-cloud

The process I want to automate with Terraform is given, at a high level, by the following 2 steps:

- Creating a VM in the Hetzner cloud provider.
- Clone via SSH a private GitHub repository, inside the VM, using cloud-init.
  What I have so far is the following Terraform snippet:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    hcloud = {
      source  = "hetznercloud/hcloud"
      version = "~> 1.42.1"
    }
  }
}

variable "HETZNER_API_KEY" {
  description = "API key for Hetzner cloud provider"
  type = string
  sensitive = true
}

# Configure the Hetzner Cloud Provider
provider "hcloud" {
  token = var.HETZNER_API_KEY # You need to define an environment variable called TF_VAR_HETZNER_API_KEY
}

data "template_file" "user_data" {
  template = file("cloud-init.yaml")
}

# Create a server
resource "hcloud_server" "costprediction" {
  name        = "costprediction"
  image       = "docker-ce"
  server_type = "cx21"
  location = "fsn1"
  user_data = data.template_file.user_data.rendered
  public_net {
    ipv4_enabled = true
    ipv6_enabled = true
  }
  ssh_keys = [hcloud_ssh_key.cost_prediction_ssh.id]
}

# Create a new SSH key
resource "hcloud_ssh_key" "cost_prediction_ssh" {
  name       = "cost_prediction_ssh"
  public_key = file("~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub")
}
```

The idea is that the initialization script of cloud-init.yaml is in charge of cloning the private repository. The problem is that, obviously, when creating an instance from scratch, it doesn't have permissions to connect to GitHub via SSH, so I can't clone the repository automatically on initialization. I understand that this is a fairly typical case, but I find it strange that I have not been able to find information about it. My thoughts would go for:

- Create an SSH peer on the VM and somehow, using perhaps the GitHub API, add the public key dynamically to the account to subsequently clone the repository.
- Add previously a public key to GitHub and using terraform incorporate this public key to the VM after its creation (I don't know if this is possible).

Does anyone know if there is a standard way to approach this problem?

Comment: I think that can be done, but you would probably need to use the `templatefile` built-in function and swap the placeholder variables in the templated file with the values you want.

Comment: I'm not familiar with hetzner cloud but if you can store a secret in a cloud service or Hashicorp Vault, then you download the SSH Key or other credentials you need to clone your repo. I've done this in AWS and works great. You can associate the permissions to your server, then use a Bash or Python script to execute in your user_data.

Answer (score 0):

> Clone via SSH a private GitHub repository, inside the VM, using cloud-init.

There is [a test in the cloud-init codebase](https://github.com/canonical/cloud-init/blob/7263cb48952446d8b2855bba7a0e0625c1557c9e/tests/integration_tests/modules/test_ansible.py#L184) that clones a private repo using [Github Deploy Keys](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/managing-deploy-keys).

It does a bunch of other stuff that you don't necessarily want too, so you don't want to copy verbatim. It sounds like you want to write a cloud-config that:

1. drops a deploy key on the instance using [the `write_files` module](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/modules.html#write-files) (see aforementioned example)
2. in [`runcmd` module](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/modules.html#runcmd) include a `git clone <url>`